# WordPress - Category.php no sidebar showing

Tags: wordpress, grid, themes

is it possible to add the homepage sidebar to a category.php page?  I use the category pages to show direct links to my post categories.  .

Example - http://bargainocity.com/category/baby-kids/

My question is if it's possible to get the sidebar thats on the home page in there in there.  I've already looked in the category.php file and I actually see both  and  but neither of those show up on the page.  Is there a trick or work around to adding it?  If so any help would be appreciated.  thanks

The them is the free them Codium Grid

any tips or help would be much appreicated

Comment: Can you include the contents of your homepage template and category.php, specifically around the get_sidebar area?

Comment: The code below is the category.php file.  Also I tried renaming the category.php file to see what WP would default them to, and it went to archive.php.  That file also doesnt seem to pull up the side bar.  So I renamed archive.php in hopes of it pulling the next default page up but whatever template it's pulling up still doesnt seem to show the sidebar string, or even the footer string from what I can tell.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/028Y3k4h

Comment: figured it out  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's possible.
First go to Posts>categories> then choose a category.
After clicking on specific category scroll down to the Layout setting option then you can choose layout with sidebar.

i guess you don't have to move on(edit) on files for this.

Comment: Hmm, I went to Posts>Categories and was presented with all of my categories. Next I clicked on Edit on one of the categories and it brings me to the Edit Category section.  Here it just has options to change the name, slug and description etc.  Is this  the same area you are talking about?  Looks similar tohttp://cdn.wpbeginner.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/edit-category-name.jpeg

Comment: ya you are on the right place scroll down below then you have to see the Layout setting option. didn't you find layout setting option ? can you show me full screenshot ?

Comment: Also, as all those items are posts under the same category. while making post, you will also see the "default layout setting option" somewhere below the editor. and those are to either show on the detail page of a single product or not.